# Angular Firefox-only Error "Argument is not a function, got undefined" in $broadcast function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firefox

I'm getting an Angular error in the console: `Error: Argument 'myControllerName' is not a function, got undefined`. Following the stack trace it appears to be coming from the `$broadcast` function, called from `updateRoute`, etc. The tricky thing is that **the error is only happening in Firefox**, not in Chrome or IE.

Setup:

- Angular v1.1.5
- Firefox 40.0.3 ***Has error***
- Chrome 45.0.2454.93 m, or IE 11.0.9600 ***Works fine***

I've looked through similar SO answers for "Argument is not a function, got undefined", but none of them address this particular issue from what I can tell. I've also checked the [Angular changelog](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.2.0/CHANGELOG.md), but see no special mention of Firefox fixes from the next version.

Does anyone know of differences between Firefox and other browsers, or any known bugs in this version of Angular, or possible causes of this error?

Comment: Can you create and post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) exhibiting this behaviour?

Comment: It seems like part of your code is either not loaded correctly or not loading at all.  To rule out cache issues, try to see if you get the same issue by opening it in a Chrome Incognito mode window

Comment: @JoseM - It works as expected in chrome incognito; error not reproducible there.

Comment: @doldt - Given the size of the app I haven't been to do that yet, but obviously that may be the only path forward.
To the down-voter: please leave a comment explaining how this question can be improved.

Comment: I wasn't that person, but **the obvious direction for improvement is posting actual code**. Without any, we can only keep guessing what might be happening. (for example, even if someone knows of an FF-specific angular bug, there's no telling whether it's actually the culprit in your case.) As an added benefit, the very path to creating an SSCCE can often reveal the source of the problem.

Comment: My question is not how to fix my code (which is too large to post) but rather *Are there any known causes/bugs/differences that would exhibit this error in Firefox?* My hope is that someone has also run into this problem (or will again in the future) and finding out the root cause will be helpful to us all.

Answer (score 0):

The underlying issue was discovered: the controller was using ES5 strict mode (`'use strict';`), and the function in question was defined too late in the scope. The solution was to simply move the location of where the offending function was defined.

So it would seem that there *are* some differences in the way Firefox handles ES5 strict mode.

From [Mozilla Developer Network's Script Mode reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode#Paving_the_way_for_future_ECMAScript_versions):

> ... Mozilla-specific caveats: ... **strict mode prohibits function statements not at the top level of a script or function.** In normal code in browsers, function statements are permitted "everywhere". This is not part of ES5 (or even ES3)! It's an extension with incompatible semantics in different browsers. Future ECMAScript editions will hopefully specify new semantics for function statements not at the top level of a script or function.

([More details here.](http://whereswalden.com/2011/01/24/new-es5-strict-mode-requirement-function-statements-not-at-top-level-of-a-program-or-function-are-prohibited/))